# Displaying a bitmap of arbitrary size without running out of memory

Tags: android, memory, android-widget, out-of-memory

How do I display an image of arbitrary size without OOMing or downscaling the image.
I dont want to downscale due to zooming and dragging of the picture?

If it isnt possible to display an image of arbitrary size, how do I determine the maximum possible size of the image to display, without causing a OOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitmap data is aloccated in the Native heap rather than the VM heap. see [BitmapFactory OOM driving me nuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955410/bitmapfactory-oom-driving-me-nuts) for details on how to monitor the Native heap and how big your bitmap can get without hitting an OOM.