# Android - AsyncTask working with Bitmap - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OutOfMemory Exception when handling images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815899/outofmemory-exception-when-handling-images)

I have a Bitmap creation within a AsyncTask, which goes like this:

```
private WeakReference<Bitmap> myBitmap;
private WeakReference<Bitmap> endResultBitmap;
private ImageView imv;
```

...

```
private class SendBitmap extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

public SendBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    myBitmap = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
  Bitmap bm = null;
  bm = getBitmapFromNet(params[0]);

  return bm;
}
```

And then I want to create Bitmap on which the received Bitmap would appear twice (one next to another)

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
  endResultBitmap = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(Bitmap.createBitmap(result.getWidth() * 2, result.getHeight(), result.getConf()));

  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(endResultBitmap.get());
  canvas.drawBitmap(result, 0, 0, null);
  canvas.drawBitmap(result, result.getWidth(), 0, null);

  imv.setImageBitmap(endResultBitmap);
}
```

then I have my onCancelled() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled(Bitmap result) {
  if(endResultBitmap!=null) {
    endResultBitmap.recycle();
    endResultBitmap = null;
  }
}
```

The thing is that if I execute this AsyncTask couple of times, the heap grows as mad. 
I execute the AsyncTask when a button is pressed, but at first I do:

```
public void onClicked(View v) {

  if(asyncTaskInstance != null) 
    asyncTaskInstance.cancel();

  asynctaskInstance.execute(2);
}
```

But again, the Heap grows as mad and at some point it will crash with **OutOfMemoryError**.

Any idea? Do I have something wrong in my Design of the task?

Comment: What is the dimension of your bitmap (result.height() ?? ) ?

Comment: ~2000 - I need that for better Quallity :(

Comment: What is **imv**? Where do you store your loaded Bitmap? ContentProvider? Memory?

Comment: Memory... because the Bitmaps should Change as I click the Button. imv is ImageView in which I want the Bitmaps to be shown.

Comment: @ Peter. Android Application has cap on total amount of memory that can be allocated. For 2 Megapixel image, the bitmap would take around 2 * 4 = 8 M memory. So  eventually you ll run out of memory!

Comment: Ok @Shash313 - I kinda know that, that's why I recycle() - what's your idea to solve the issue? plus I use largeHeap on Honeycomb.

Answer (score 1):

Android has some memory limits for apps (16 MB if i remember correctly), and that image is too big in an uncompressed format. Theres some interesting discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue).

To solve it, there are afaik only two ways:
 1. Reduce the size of the image to consume less memory
 2. Load the image in native code using the NDK.

To 1.: I don't know what exactly you are trying to do and can't tell if thats really a viable option. If it is, you may want download the image file from the net and open it with the `BitmapFactory` class. There are some static functions that take an [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) object. Use inSampleSize from this Options object to reduce the image size by a certain factor at loading time (inSampleSize should be a power of two by the way).

To 2.: The memory limits that I mentioned above don't apply to native code. So you may be able to load the image and display in a native way. I don't have any experience with that, I just know that it's possible, but googling around should turn up a few results.

Comment: I cannot resize since I need that quality I get from the web.

Comment: As said above, if you can only download one fixed quality from the web, download the whole image from the web and save it in a cache directory. From there, load it via the BitmapFactory with a reduced size into the memory to circumvent the restrictions.

Comment: I will try that. Just for info, now if I click the Button 10 times, it will start 10 different AsyncTasks and at some point will throw "Grow heap (frag case) to 221.454MB for 14313056-byte allocation" message and OutOfMemoryException after that.