# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am trying to change the layout of my application from portrait to landscape and vice-versa. 
But if i do it frequently or  more than once then at times my application crashes.. Below is the error log. Please suggest what can be done?

```
 01-06 09:52:27.787: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(17473): 1550532-byte external allocation too large for this process. 01-06 09:52:27.787: ERROR/dalvikvm(17473): Out of memory: Heap Size=6471KB, Allocated=4075KB, Bitmap Size=9564KB 
 01-06 09:52:27.787: ERROR/(17473): VM won't let us allocate 1550532 bytes 
 01-06 09:52:27.798: DEBUG/skia(17473): --- decoder->decode returned false
 01-06 09:52:27.798: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(17473): Shutting down VM
 01-06 09:52:27.798: WARN/dalvikvm(17473): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e390)
 01-06 09:52:27.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3812) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1936) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1629) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at onCreate(Game.java:98)
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     ...  12 more
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:92) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     ...  22 more
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:464) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:340) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1705) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1799) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:296) 
 01-06 09:52:27.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17473):     ...  26 more
```

Comment: next time, use the "format code" button, not the "block quote" button. the blockquote button mess up the message

Comment: I am also getting this error, but there are no any solution.
I am getting this error when i am trying to get the frame of video file from MetaDataRetriver class, 

My Code
 MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

mRetriever.setDataSource(this.videoPath);

for (int i = 0; i < TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
       .toMicros(listVideoFileDuration.get(k)); i = i + 5000000) {


Bitmap oragnalBitmap = mRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i,
        MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_NEXT_SYNC);
}

Answer (score 12):

I had got the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Bitmap Size Exceeds VM Budget error at several times

1) When switching from app and back to the app some time later (Press home button and after browsing some url)

2) When login/logout to app frequently (within 10 seconds)

3) When switching the device horizontally/vertically

Finally I solved the error in following way

```
    public void clearAllResources() {

    // Set related variables null

    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
   }
```

Comment: As the Android performance documentation states you should not be attempting to force the GC, you should let Davlik handle it itself. At best this hiding the cause of your memory issue and substituting a CPU performance loss.

Comment: @Rafiq, could you please explain when to call this function clearAllResources()?

Answer (score 8):

This is a practical answer, what I tried to avoid this problem at Run-time

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

Calling Garbage Collector is a good Idea.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line of code  to Android Manifest File inside "application" tag: - android:largeHeap="true"

```
<application
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       >
```

Answer (score 3):

You are leaking resources (most likely the `Drawable` object).  Try the tools in [What Android tools and methods work best to find memory/resource leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/)

Answer (score 3):

Where does the image source come from? Do you have a 9MB image in your drawables folder?

There's a lot of discussion on issues with Android's native bitmap memory management, e.g. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10821, http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488, http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ed57849ef705d421/11af8362d77a8cf4?lnk=raot . I've had good luck explicitly invoking recycle() and System.gc() every time I am finished with a bitmap, e.g.:

```
private void changeImage() {
     if (mCurrentImage != null) {
          mCurrentImage.recycle();
          mCurrentImage = null;
          System.gc();
     }
     mCurrentImage = getNewImage();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First stop your application from crashing at run time by catching the OutOfMemory error at place which you think can generate this error as below:

```
try {

...

}
catch(OutOfMemoryError error)  {
    //decide what to do when there is not more memory available
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the problem using `opts.inSampleSize=2; or opts.inSampleSize=4`

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
// opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
opts.inSampleSize=2;    
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(st_imagepath,opts);
```

Answer (score 2):

Angel,  there is a similar problem posted on StackOverflow here @ [OutOfMemory exception when loading bitmap from external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102758/outofmemory-exception-when-loading-bitmap-from-external-storage/4134307#4134307)

And from there I inferenced SoftReference could also be an alternative for the solution .Do check the post it might prove helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I made a couple of extensions to @hp.android's excellent answer:

1. Instead of defining a RootView ID in each XML class, I dynamically find the root view using `android.R.id.content`.
2. As @Mario Lenci says, AdapterView doesn't support removeAllViews, so I check the type of the view before calling `removeAllViews()`.
3. IMO it isn't a good idea to call `System.gc()` in every onDestroy call (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3118939/112705)), so I've removed that.
4. I've made a static `onDestroy` method that I call from onDestroy in all my custom Activity classes.
5. I've added some extra error protection and logging.

Here's the code:

```
    public static void onDestroy(Activity activity) {
        View rootView = null;

        try {            
            rootView = ((ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content))
                    .getChildAt(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Cannot find root view to call unbindDrawables on",
                  activity);
        }

        if (rootView != null) {
            Log.d("unbindDrawables", activity, rootView);
            unbindDrawables(rootView);
        }
    }

    /**
      * Utility method to unbind drawables when an activity is destroyed.  This
      * ensures the drawables can be garbage collected.
      */
     public static void unbindDrawables(View view) {
         if (view.getBackground() != null) {
             view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
         }

         if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
             for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                 unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
             }

             try {                
                 // AdapterView objects do not support the removeAllViews method
                 if (!(view instanceof AdapterView)) {             
                     ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
                 }
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.w("Ignore Exception in unbindDrawables", e);
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A 1550532 byte allocation sounds big. I'm guessing your layout has a reference to a bitmap image of some kind, a PNG perhaps? What are the dimensions of this PNG? If it is really big and you have more than a couple of them you might just not have enough memory to load them all at once.

Also if this is triggered by the rotation remember that your Activity is destroyed and recreated so you might need to be careful of static references. Take a look at this [Google blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html). You'll need to be careful of keeping static references to things in your code which may result in leaks

Answer (score 0):

http://yekmer.posterous.com/android-memory-management

might be help this site.And you should  free all reference .