# Android OutOfMemoryError while using multiple images

Tags: android, memory-management, android-emulator, android-imageview, performance

In my application, i have 3 screens containing multiple high resolution images. The number of images used in a screen is around 70-75. I have written the code to add images in a grid layout using an adapter class extending BaseAdapter, in the getView() method i wrote the code,

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

int x = (int)(width/5.1f);
imageView.setId(position);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(x,x));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(4, 20, 4, 20);
```

but while loading this screen, it show lots of memory issues, and in logcat i am getting the error,

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Please share how could i write the code to handle memory issues with multiple high resolution images. Thanks.

Comment: 70-75... what are surprise, huh? ) Place here code of your ImageAdapter

Comment: You should use thumbnails, only solutions...

Comment: check this link also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611822/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget

Comment: As Ferdau said, you should generate smaller sized images (thumbnails) to display as grid, and only display full res image when users require it (by clicking on an image for example). This will solve your memory issue and run much faster.

Comment: ya thats right. thanks Ferdau and kai.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to adjust the images resolutions you should open them as `BitmapFactory.Options().inJustDecodeBounds = true`, pass your options to the images (desired adjusted size) and then decode them again using `BitmapFactory.Options().inJustDecodeBounds = false`.

The actual byte size of a bitmap image is calculated by multiplying the number of pixels by then number of bytes allocated for the pixel. `ARGB_8888` (which is recommended) allocates 4 bytes per pixel, therefore, the size will be **width * height * 4 Bytes**.

For more details read the [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) lesson from Android. Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10156813/935627) should help.