# BitmapFactory.decodeStream() returns a Bitmap ~100 times more than original

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, filesize, bitmapfactory

I have a PNG image of 168.2KB and 1991x1756 and tried to import it into a `Bitmap` using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. The problem is that I run into `OutOfMemoryError` where the `Bitmap` size ends up being 13,657KB. 
What I don't understand is why is the file so big after the import and how to mitigate this.  
Seems that this `OutOfMemoryError` issue is very common with decoded `Bitmap` images but can't find a way to fix it. Any ideas?

`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bitmapOptions);`

`E/AndroidRuntime(10744): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=7815KB, Allocated=3279KB, Bitmap Size=13657KB)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A png-file is highly compressed, meaning that the file size on disk is much smaller than it would be when all the data it contains is loaded into memory.
A bitmap is a very simple representation of an image, where every pixel is represented by a value. The size of this value depends on the current settings (you may have heard of 32-bit images, 16 bit images or 8 bit images which are some common sizes).

To calculate the true size of an image represented as a bitmap you have to calculate the number of pixels, and multiply this with how many bits you have for each pixel.
Your image is 1991x1756 pixels (**3 496 196** pixels in total). If you load the bitmap using ARGB_8888 format (one byte for each color/alpha channel = 4 bytes per pixel) you end up with `3 496 196 * 4 =` **`13 984 784`** bytes.

You can reduce the total size by using fewer bytes/channel (RGB_565 for example) although this also reduces the quality of your image. A better option would most likely be to reduce the size of your images, or import them using the [`inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) parameter in your `BitmapFactory.Options` to load a smaller image.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the PNG image is heavily compressed, but bitmaps in android are not compressed as there are 4 bytes per pixel (ARGB)

so 1991 * 1756 * (4 bytes) is about 13657 KB

So try using a smaller image or insample size Options for bitmap options to reduce the size.

Take a look at this post:
[Decoding bitmaps in Android with the right size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641726/decoding-bitmaps-in-android-with-the-right-size)