# Android Error: Memory Issues?

Tags: java, android

so i came across some errors and i've searched it up. it seems i have some memory issues. but im not quite sure on how to solve it. here's the codes where i believe the problem lies with and also the error log. any help would be highly appreciated

```
static List<Dragon> mdragon = new ArrayList<Dragon>();
private int mdragon_number = 0;

   @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (mdragon) {
        mdragon.add(new Dragon(getResources(), (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY()));
        mdragon_number = mdragon.size();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void Remove(long elapsed, Canvas canvas) {
    synchronized (mdragon) {
        List<Dragon> toRemove = new ArrayList<Dragon>();
        for (Dragon dragon : mdragon) {
            if (Condition to remove an element) 
                toRemove.add(dragon);
            }
            mdragon.removeAll(toRemove);
    }
}
```

Error Log below:

```
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:346)
07-13 02:11:46.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:372)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably storing references to some bitmap images in the vm memory which are not getting de-allocated in time / when you activity gets finished . Hence [no more memory](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) is left to play with.

Try implementing a logic that does not store images in memory, also try scaling down the images if they are huge.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your problem is related to `BitmapFactory` options. In order to save VM resources you'd better use special options for `BitmapFactory`:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPurgeable=true; //declare as purgeable to disk
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context, R.drawable.myDrawable, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of bitmap memory in the native heap - see [BitmapFactory OOM driving me nuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955410/bitmapfactory-oom-driving-me-nuts/5493182#5493182)