# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset()

Tags: java, android, error-handling, bitmap, horizontalscrollview

Hi i am creating an app about traffic signs. traffic signs are in .png format. some of them I am showing in horizontalscrollview. But when try to open activities , I get this error from android market error reports. here is my error report:

```
<java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.besalti.svenskavagmarken/com.besalti.svenskavagmarken.varningsmarken}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #645: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #645: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:227)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at com.besalti.svenskavagmarken.varningsmarken.onCreate(varningsmarken.java:25)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:494)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:370)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:715)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1720)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:122)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
... 29 more>
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show us the code for varningsmarken.java and the layout xml file for it.  Apparently you have a Typearray too.  Also what is the size of the image that is bein loaded in the imageview?

Comment: Post up the fix so that others may learn from you, that is what this site is about...plus I am curioud too.

Comment: @ErkanBeşaltı please post the fix.

Comment: I am facing same issue , please post the fix !

Answer (score 3):

The "bitmap size exceeds VM budget" error is actually in the native graphics library (Skia). It is a tad confusing as the problem is really that Skia has run out of memory in the native heap for bitmap data. See [BitmapFactory OOM driving me nuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955410/bitmapfactory-oom-driving-me-nuts/5493182) for background.
To get round this, you will have to look carefully at your bitmap usage

- making sure that you do not leave bitmap references floating
- doing a recycle / null onn bitmaps as they become free (this appears to help).

Answer (score 2):

Use sampling to read bitmap. May be error occurred due to memory leaks.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;

Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);
```