# Take picture with camera before starting new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have an activity that will take a picture upon touch of the screen. After taking the picture, I'd like to switch to a different activity. The structure of the code looks like the following:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements onTouchListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mCameraView.takePicture();
        // Intent intent = new Intent(whatever);
        // startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
   }
```

As shown, if I commented out the `startActivity`, then picture is taken and saved correctly. If I attempt to start the activity AFTER taking the picture, then the picture is not saved correctly (size 0). I don't know for sure if the picture taking is in a separate thread or not, but even if it is, it should **eventually** saved, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your activity at the end of `Camera.PictureCallback()`

```
mCameraView.takePicture(new Camera.ShutterCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onShutter() {
                        Log.e("Shutter closed", "   SHUTTER    callback");

                    }
                }, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
                        Log.e("Picture taken",
                                "   RAW    image    callback");
                    }
                }, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
                        Log.e("Picture taken",
                                "   POSTVIEW    image    callback");
                    }
                }, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        // Start Activity here after saving image
                    }
                });


            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: This method works on taking the first picture. Upon taking the second shot, OOM (Out of Memory) kicks in. It may not related to the method per se though, still looking into it. Thanks

Comment: OOM occur due to less memory for your application. May be the `Bitmap` you are creating is large.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419140/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-in-android-while-saving-picture-taken-from-camera