# intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE kills activity and app Android 4.1

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, galaxy-tab

I have a Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 GT-P3110, and something strange happens when I try to access the camera with intent. In one activity I have 20 buttons that call the intent to access the camera, but the activity falls randomly. Sometimes the photograph taken correctly, but sometimes not and throws the following error:

```
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {cl.prosys.rac/cl.prosys.rac.activity.FormularioInspeccionActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {cl.prosys.rac/cl.prosys.rac.activity.FormularioInspeccionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2127)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3550)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {cl.prosys.rac/cl.prosys.rac.activity.FormularioInspeccionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3179)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2600)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    ... 13 more
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at cl.prosys.rac.activity.FormularioInspeccionActivity.onActivityResult(FormularioInspeccionActivity.java:684)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5347)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3175)
04-17 17:43:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(30159):    ... 14 more
```

After that the Activity is restarted. And the source code is:

```
public void onTakePicture(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(photoPathTemp)));
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        GalleryButton btn = (GalleryButton) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(photoKey, "id", getPackageName()));
        savePhotos(btn.width, btn.height);
        setBackgroundButton(btn, photoPathThumb);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do some weird wizardry with findViewById. Should you add null check just in case?

Comment: savePhotos(btn.width, btn.height); I add a validation if btn ​​is null. Now does not throw any error, but the activity is restarting. Will it be the camera app the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of _[Android startCamera gives me null Intent and ... does it destroy my global variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424909/android-startcamera-gives-me-null-intent-and-does-it-destroy-my-global-varia)_

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Activity getting Destroyed after calling Camera Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014930/android-activity-getting-destroyed-after-calling-camera-intent)