# android Rotation cause NullPointerException when capture photo

Tags: android-camera, android-manifest

I am using android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in menifest. But still its refresh my activity. Here is my activity tag in menifest.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.paksoft.people.MiActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

Comment: You use camera intent to take picture, don't you?

Comment: Yes i am using camera intent

Comment: Check [this][1] link.All you have get the perfect solution from here.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30590143/1071545

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that launching of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent will push your activity out of memory. See for example: *[Android startCamera gives me null Intent and ... does it destroy my global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424909/android-startcamera-gives-me-null-intent-and-does-it-destroy-my-global-varia)*

In this situation, `onCreate()` of your activity is called before `onActivityResult()`. You should prepare your activity to reinitialize itself, probably using `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Note that the decision whether to shut down the activity, or keep it in background, depends on the overall system state that is beyond your control.

PS: `android:configChanges` attribute is irrelevant because the activity is destroyed not as response of the system to orientation switch (and this cannot happen with `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`), but because the system resources are drained by launching the Camera app to fullfill the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent.