# Android openFileChooser onCreate() called after onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, onactivityresult, onrestoreinstancestate

I have a webview and on one of the pages there is an Upload Photo button. I found some code to implement the file chooser (Android, why so hard????) and if I pick the gallery everything works fine. If I choose camera 1 of 10 times it works. But most of the time when I take the picture and click save (this is all in the camera activity) the webview loads the first page loaded when the app was started. It seems that the `onActivityResult()` is not called but instead of it `onCreate()` is and this messes up my app. Can you give me an example of how to restore the webView state after I take the picture? (maybe I should mention that I am logged in in the WebView).

This is the WebChromeClient class:

```
public class WebViewChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private Activity activity;
    public Uri imageUri;

    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

    private Context context;

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public WebViewChromeClient(Context context, Activity activity,
            MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

        // Update message
        ((Audi) activity.getApplication()).setmUploadMessage(uploadMsg);

        if (uploadMsg == null) {
            Log.d("UPLOAD MESSAGE", "NULL");
        }

        try {
            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "AndroidExampleFolder");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mainActivity.setmCapturedImageURI(mCapturedImageURI);
            Log.d("Line", "57");
            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            mainActivity.setmCapturedImageURI(mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                    new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    // openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
            String acceptType, String capture) {

        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }

    // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a
    // console message informing what action to perform,android wml_siso init 
    // taking a photo or updating the file

    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {

        onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
        return true;
    }

    public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
         Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: "
         + message);

    }

}
```

And this is the onActivityResult method:

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {

    webView.requestFocus();

    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onActivityResult");

        if (null == ((Audi) getApplication()).getmUploadMessage()) {
            Log.d("FileChooser Result", "58");
            return;
        }

        Log.d("MainActivity", "onActivityResult");
        Uri result = null;

        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                result = null;
            } else {
                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent
                        .getData();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        ((Audi) getApplication()).getmUploadMessage().onReceiveValue(result);
        ((Audi) getApplication()).setmUploadMessage(null);
    }
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onActivityResult");
}
```

Comment: _[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424909/android-startcamera-gives-me-null-intent-and-does-it-destroy-my-global-varia)_ a similar situation is described, with a solution.

Comment: I didn't understand how to save the webview state and restore it. If I restore it in onRestoreInstanceState() the page does not take the picture from the camera.. Would you give me an example?

Comment: Wait a sec. Why does `onRestoreInstanceState()` conflict with camera? Or, you don't see the `onActivityResult()` called in this case?

Comment: Most of the time onActivityResult() is not called but onCreate() is.

Comment: I never saw `onActivityResult()` not called at all. Sometimes, it's called at time you least expect it, or with requestCode/resultCode combination you could not imagine to be possible. Double check your logs.

Comment: Yes.. you're right. It is called but it is called before onCreate() and everything goes wrong when the onCreate is called because it takes me to a different page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding this line in the Manifest `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Answer (score 1):

Your activity is probably being paused/stopped by the system while you run the file chooser.

You need to handle `onResume()` and restore your activity's previous state. The `onResume` method is invoked when your activity is restarted, so this is a good place to reload whatever WebView you were displaying before launching the file chooser.

Comment: what should I do in the onResume?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your posted code, here is a dangerous line:

```
webView.requestFocus();
```

is first in `onActivityResult()`. If **MainActivity** is being recreated, this could cause **NullPointerException**. The system will seamlessly re-launch your app, possibly producing the reported behavior.

Add another Log.d() to the beginning of `onActivityResult()`, put try/catch around this dangerous line, *and* use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().

Note that if your **MainActivity** is Portrait, you face extra trouble, with Camera app forcing Landscape.