# How to upload image from webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I've got a problem with the webview embeded in my app (Android 4.4.4+). On a page there is an "Upload image" button I manage with `openFileChooser`.

On some devices, when I click on the "Upload image" button in the webview, the camera app is launched and my app is destroyed. After taking the picture my app is recreated, I restore the webview state (saved in `onSaveInstanceState`) and the `onActivityResult()` is called.  The problem is that the variable `mUploadMessage` containing the `ValueCallBack` is null, so I'm not able to invoke the `ValueCallBack.onReceiveValue()` to give the image URI to the webview.

```
// openFileChooser for Android 3.0+ to 4.4
// WARNING: the openFileChooser works in version 4.4 only for 4.4.3+
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
    // Update message
    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
    fileChooserManagement(FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    webview.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state
        webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Do not test the resultCode, because it's mandatory to enter the 'if' and to call the
    // onReceiveValue even with null. Otherwise the openFileChooser will not be called anymore.
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (this.mUploadMessage == null) {
            Log.i("myApp", "onActivityResult mUploadMessage is null");
            return;
        }
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(processPicture(resultCode, data));
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

There's a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781818/android-openfilechooser-oncreate-called-after-onactivityresult), but the question "I didn't understand how to save the webview state and restore it. If I restore it in onRestoreInstanceState() the page does not take the picture from the camera.. Would you give me an example?" has no answer.

Thank you for your help guys!