# Intent Camera Crashes the application

Tags: android, camera, crash

I am using the following code to capture the image it is working fine in the all version of android except Android 5.0.1. Please help to detect the error in the code. I have also add all the permissions that required by the app.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and onActivityResult as below

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            ""+R.string.folder_name);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {

            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}


public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
             BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

             // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
             // images
             options.inSampleSize = 8;

             final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                     options);

             createComplaint.setPhotoBitmap(bitmap);
                imgVPicPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } else if (resultCode == 0) {
            // user cancelled Image capture

        } else {
            // failed to capture image

        }
    }
}
```

Logcat Error Message -

```
07-04 18:25:47.513: E/AndroidRuntime(13968): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference
```

07-04 18:25:47.513: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at com.myaccessibility.newcomplaint.NewPhotoFragment.onActivityResult(NewPhotoFragment.java:379)
07-04 18:25:47.513: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:167)
07-04 18:25:47.513: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at com.myaccessibility1.MyAccessibility.onActivityResult(MyAccessibility.java:734)
07-04 18:25:47.513: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6543)
07-04 18:25:47.513: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4054)

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android startCamera gives me null Intent and ... does it destroy my global variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424909/android-startcamera-gives-me-null-intent-and-does-it-destroy-my-global-varia)

Answer (score 0):

`fileUri` is `null`.

Please bear in mind that your process may be terminated while you are in the background. This includes when your app is asking another app to take a picture. You need to make sure that you can rebuild your environment when your process is started up again. For example, `fileUri` might need to be put into the `Bundle` supplied to `onSaveInstanceState()`, then restored from the `Bundle` supplied to `onRestoreInstanceState()`. You should be doing this to deal with configuration changes as well, such as the user rotating the screen.

You can read more about [the process model](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle) and [handling configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) in the documentation.