# Fragment get closed after Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, camera

I am taking picture using camera intent in a fragment. On some devices it works perfect but on some devices my fragment get closed after taking picture.

Here is my code of calling camera intent:

```
Intent picIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(picIntent, Constants.TAKE_PICTURE_SIGN_UP);
```

Here is my MainActivity's onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == Constants.TAKE_PICTURE_SIGN_UP || requestCode == Constants.SELECT_PICTURE_SIGN_UP)
    {
        SignUpFragment frag = (SignUpFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.SignUpFragmentTag);
        if(frag != null && frag.isVisible())
        {
            frag.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

When I select picture from gallery it works fine but when I take picture from camera frag is null. What cause the problem here and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using the ChildFragmentManager? Because on some device onActivityResult not work correctly if the fragment is a ChildFragment and the onActivityResult are catched by the main Activity closing your fragment

Comment: protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }  
    }

Comment: I am using SupportFragmentManager. As fragment has on 1 parent activity i.e. MainActivity. On selecting picture from gallery I am able to find fragment tag but on taking picture from camera findFragmentByTag return null. @DarioPicco

Comment: This is but another example of *[Activity getting Destroyed after calling Camera Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014930/android-activity-getting-destroyed-after-calling-camera-intent)* phenomenon. This may happen sometimes, on some devices more often than on others.

The fix is to implement save/restore of instance state. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26708283/192373) for code snippets.

Comment: @MianAzhar Hi, did you got any solution? M facing same issue.

Comment: @Nitish Yes I got solution. I have added it to answer of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following coe and it worked for me

```
Intent picIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp1.jpg");
Uri mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

picIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(picIntent, Constants.TAKE_PICTURE_SIGN_UP);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@Mina Azhar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695786/1283715),
you have to handle when system kill background activities on low memory.

```
fragment.startActivityForResult(picIntent, Constants.TAKE_PICTURE_SIGN_UP);
```

- You need to save fragment state,

  ```
  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
     outState.putParcelable("cameraMediaOutputUri", mImageCaptureUri);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }
  ```

**Restoring Fragment State** [Fragment Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState !=null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("cameraMediaOutputUri"))
        mImageCaptureUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("cameraMediaOutputUri");
}
```

Comment: This worked, but very ofter the state of fragment gets lost

Answer (score 0):

Use a method like this to make sure your fragment is attached and displayed:

```
private MyFragmentA switchToFragmentA(){

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyFragmentA fragment = (MyFragmentA) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_A);

    if(fragment == null){
        fragment = MyFragmentA.newInstance();
    }

    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, TAG_A).commit();

    return fragment;
}
```

Then adjust your onActivityResult like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == Constants.TAKE_PICTURE_SIGN_UP || requestCode == Constants.SELECT_PICTURE_SIGN_UP){
        switchToFragmentA().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 3 fragments A, B and C. From MainActivity I go to fragment A and from there I go to fragment B and then finally I move to fragment C where I am taking picture. Then how am I supposed to keep reference of fragment C?

Comment: I've taken a new approach based on you having three fragments - you can have three methods like the one in my answer, one for each fragment. Then you'll know it's always there and available

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** : is that the Camera activity destroys your activity and fragments. Now the proper solution is implementing `onSaveInstanceState` methods of all fragments and activities.

**Last Resort Quick Solution** : is to set activity to not destroy on orientation changes and screen re-size etc. For this in your manifest file for the main activity or the activity having that particular fragment add this line

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity_"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
</activity>
```

Read here about [android:configChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)