# Android - Failure to get image from camera intent on 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-camera, nexus-10

I'm trying to take photo and than get file path by calling:

```
Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camera_intent, Static.TAKE_PICTURE);
```

and than:

```
case Static.TAKE_PICTURE:
if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){  
    if(data.getData() != null){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String path = selectedImage.getPath();
        if(path.contains("images/media")){
            path = Static.getImageRealPathFromURI(getActivity().getBaseContext(),selectedImage);
        }
    }
}
break;
```

working fine on 4.1.2 Galaxy S3, but crashes every time on 4.2.2 Nexus 10 with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65642, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.******.***/com.******.***.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If I try do the same for Video:

```
Intent video_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(video_intent, Static.RECORD_VIDEO);
```

works fine. Really I don't have idea why.

Comment: **Provide complete error traces.** Are you observing crash before capturing image i.e on just load of capture intent or after capturing an image..

Comment: App crashes when it's trying come back from Camera Intent. There is just null data in result.

Comment: take a [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11351580/2345913)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
photoFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + Static.genereateFileName() + ".jpg";  
File imageFile = new File(photoFilePath); 
Uri imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
camera_intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri); 
startActivityForResult(camera_intent, Static.TAKE_PICTURE);
```