# Camera App using ACTION_CAPTURE_IMAGE crashing

Tags: android

**I am trying to make a app that opens camera and captured photo displays in my app main activity's ImageView. but app is crashing when I'm running the camera Intent.**

here is my MainActivity.class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;
public void capture(View v){
  MainActivity m=new MainActivity();
  m.captureImage();

}

public void captureImage(){
    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
        startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ImageView iv=findViewById(R.id.myimage);
        iv.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }    }
}
```

any one out there to help will be thankful.

Comment: You need to post more (stacktrace) information and you should scan SO [for the same kind of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504717/android-app-crashes-on-onactivityresult-while-using-camera-intent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you never ever create a instance of an Activity.

> MainActivity m=new MainActivity();//  Wrong

Intent is the API which allow that, to communicate between Android's Components . And about calling methods-> You are calling method in same class why you creating an object just call it . It will Call with current reference anyway .

```
public void capture(View v){
captureImage();
}
```

Comment: why do i don't create instance of an activity

Comment: Cause activity is instantiated via intent. Read the documentation for more.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new Instance of MainActivity, Ignore this use only.

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;
public void capture(View v){
   captureImage();
}
```

And Make Sure Camera Permission is added on Manifest.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

And if working with Android M+ pleas check runtime camera permission is given.

Comment: I do not think that hardware permission needed to access camera using intent

Comment: Please refer (Best Practice only) https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html